# In my website, how can I know which pages users have clicked on my AdSense ads?

Tags: google-analytics, adsense

I have linked Google AdSense account with my Google Analytics two months ago. Now, I want to know in which pages users have clicked ads. From Google AdSense dashboard I can get valuable information but not this one in concret; neither in Google Analytics.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Analytics, you have to configure an AdSense Linking (https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6084409?hl=en) then you can find pages/clicks report in '`Behavior --> Publisher --> Publisher pages`'.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I know what is the purpose of Publisher section.